# How to remove swatch options that are not available?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, swatches

in magento RWD theme, I would like to alter the way the swatches function so that subsequent swatches are dependant on the previous selection, and unavailable swatches to be removed.

For example,

a product has three options: design, colour, and size.

design 1 is available in colours white and pink and in size large. whereas, say design 2 is available in colours black, white, pink and yellow; and sizes medium and large.

so, if I were to first choose design 1, the below swatches wouldn't have options black and yellow for colour and size medium.

But if I chose design 2 it would have swatches available for colours black, white, pink and yellow; and sizes medium and large.

I believe the code that handles the swatches is in

```
/skin/rwd/default/js/configurableswatches/swatches-product.js
```

But, sadly I am struggling to identify how I can correctly amend this code to get what I'm after.

Update:

[image: Greyed out only]

As this image shows, Menus are not available in size 'A5 double sided'. Ideally it would remove this option when Menus is chosen and add it when booking form selected. Same for others.

Update 2:

```
opt._e.li[method]('no-display');
```

Will toggle the hiding of below 'not-available' options. But, if selection made below and then above option is changed, and below selection is not available with the new above option all other options are no longer visible.

[image: options all hidden]

As image above illustrates:

Menu was first selected. Then the option a4 long fold was chosen. Then option above was changed to booking form. Consequently, as the option a4 long fold isn't available with booking form, a 'not-available' option is selected. Resulting in the pack size option having all of it's options hidden, as by default when this occurs Magento does this :

[image: default not-available selection result]

Answer (score 0):

The swatches do work like that only by default provided the products are setup correctly. I believe you're using Configurable Products on your website.

So, as per the example given : *design 1 is available in colours white and pink and in size large. whereas, say design 2 is available in colours black, white, pink and yellow; and sizes medium and large.*

Now, ideally, you should have a Configurable Product with Simple Associated Products as under :

a. Design 1 + White + Large
b. Design 1 + Pink + Large
c. Design 2 + Black + Medium
d. Design 2 + Black + Large
and so on...

Thus, as the user select Design 1, only the colors White & Pink shall show. You need not modify any code in Magento in order to achieve this.

Comment: Hi Saurabh all options show only a grey stroke is put through the unavailable options and basket changed to state 'out of stock'.

Comment: @Vaishal Patel Could you please share the URL of your website ? I can check it and suggest accordingly.

Comment: Saurabh the site is on a local server

Answer (score 0):

If you get some css class change then you can simply do `display:none` to that swatches which is not avliable. I think this is the quickest solution for your problem

For example

```
 li.swatch.disable{
  display:none;
 }
 li.swatch{
   display : block;
 }
```

**Class name should be change as per your class** But I am definetly sure this will solve your problem

Comment: I thought this but I tried adding opt._e.li[method]('no-display'); Hides them, but issues when changing selection

Comment: for that you have to add two css if you see not-avliable then only add display:none otherwise it should be`display:block`

Comment: But with `display: none` options below the option where unavailable selection is chosen will be all hidden.

Comment: can you give me link ?

Comment: It is on my local server sadly :( see update 2, iv'e added further detail

Comment: Dont do it with js do with css only

Comment: That line of code only adds display: none. The issues is the selection of not-available option.

Comment: Maybe if there is a way to reset slections

Comment: Please check my updated answer

Comment: If user selects an option then changes above option. Making the below option unavailable, then all other options dissappear.

Comment: If user click on some option then only classes were chnage by JS so dont worry about that

Comment: But magento adds not-available class to every option when unavailable option selected. Thus all option dissapper. See update two above